# How to say "the same below" in academic papers?

Tags: expressions

Simply put, if I use a notation and do not want to repeat noting that again and again in the rest of the paper, what should I write? The meaning I want to express is that this notation carries the same meaning unless otherwise stated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that if you establish a notation within an academic paper, then it is implicit that the notation will be understood as introduced within the scope of that paper. Indeed I do not see how one could, and why one would, easily depart from this natural understanding. Highlighting graphically the definition for the notation is a good idea. In case you need to be explicit, people do say "for the rest of this paper" or "within (the scope of) this paper", and similar turns of phrase.

Comment: Makes sense. I like your argument. In my case, I frequently use math equations. Some notations, I guess, may be too common and conventional, yet I find that people still tend to emphasize their definitions here and there. Thus I'm a bit not so confident in this sense...

Comment: @anemone For most academic papers one is given a word limit. For my MA dissertation, because of the nature of the research, I was given a dispensation on footnotes. So it was often easier to say something by way of footnote than to include it in the text. So perhaps a footnote indicating the abbreviated form which will follow is what is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

*In this account I will describe the conditions in both the war zone, and the de-militarised zone (hereafter the WZ and the DMZ respectively).*?

Comment: "Hereafter", exactly what I'm looking for. :)